# Insert into Linked table in access without the primary key

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

Im trying to insert into a linked SQL table in access 2007, below is my query

```
INSERT INTO tblProducts ( ProductPrefix, ProductCode, ProductDescription, MadeFrom, MadeFromDescription, SamFamilySort1, SamFamilySort2, SamFamilySort3, SamFamilySort4, SamFamilySort5, Grade, Length, Thickness, fWidth, Factor, CubicMtrs, CubicMtrsFull, [Weight(T)], DrawingFilepath, EFACSProductGrouping, BatchSize, PackSize, Density, createdby, createddate, ProductType, customer, DimA, DimB, DimC, DimD, DimE, DimF, DimG, DimH, DimI, DimJ, DimK, DimL, DimM, DimN, DimO, DimP, DimQ, DimR, DimS, DimT, DimU, DimV, DimW, DimX, DimY, DimZ, TolA, TolB, TolC, TolD, TolE, TolF, TolG, TolH, TolI, TolJ, TolK, TolL, TolM, TolN, TolO, TolP, TolQ, TolR, TolS, TolT, TolU, TolV, TolW, TolX, TolY, TolZ, Dimension, Main, Saws, Moulders, PaintLines, XCut, DET, Wrapper, Blocks, HingeRecess, reorderpolicy, machinedaway, UseOtherM3XC, UseOtherM3MS, ShrinkWrap, ShrinkWrapPackSize, SW, samtype1, vtype1, vtype2, profile, productchamp, UOM, SAMPartGrp, PostingClass, ProductID )
SELECT DISTINCT tblProducts.ProductPrefix, tblProducts.ProductCode, tblProducts.ProductDescription, tblProducts.MadeFrom, tblProducts.MadeFromDescription, tblProducts.SamFamilySort1, tblProducts.SamFamilySort2, tblProducts.SamFamilySort3, tblProducts.SamFamilySort4, tblProducts.SamFamilySort5, tblProducts.Grade, tblProducts.Length, tblProducts.Thickness, tblProducts.fWidth, tblProducts.Factor, tblProducts.CubicMtrs, tblProducts.CubicMtrsFull, tblProducts.[Weight(T)], tblProducts.DrawingFilepath, tblProducts.EFACSProductGrouping, tblProducts.BatchSize, tblProducts.PackSize, tblProducts.Density, tblProducts.createdby, Date() AS Expr1, tblProducts.ProductType, tblProducts.customer, tblProducts.DimA, tblProducts.DimB, tblProducts.DimC, tblProducts.DimD, tblProducts.DimE, tblProducts.DimF, tblProducts.DimG, tblProducts.DimH, tblProducts.DimI, tblProducts.DimJ, tblProducts.DimK, tblProducts.DimL, tblProducts.DimM, tblProducts.DimN, tblProducts.DimO, tblProducts.DimP, tblProducts.DimQ, tblProducts.DimR, tblProducts.DimS, tblProducts.DimT, tblProducts.DimU, tblProducts.DimV, tblProducts.DimW, tblProducts.DimX, tblProducts.DimY, tblProducts.DimZ, tblProducts.TolA, tblProducts.TolB, tblProducts.TolC, tblProducts.TolD, tblProducts.TolE, tblProducts.TolF, tblProducts.TolG, tblProducts.TolH, tblProducts.TolI, tblProducts.TolJ, tblProducts.TolK, tblProducts.TolL, tblProducts.TolM, tblProducts.TolN, tblProducts.TolO, tblProducts.TolP, tblProducts.TolQ, tblProducts.TolR, tblProducts.TolS, tblProducts.TolT, tblProducts.TolU, tblProducts.TolV, tblProducts.TolW, tblProducts.TolX, tblProducts.TolY, tblProducts.TolZ, tblProducts.Dimension, tblProducts.Main, tblProducts.Saws, tblProducts.Moulders, tblProducts.PaintLines, tblProducts.XCut, tblProducts.DET, tblProducts.Wrapper, tblProducts.Blocks, tblProducts.HingeRecess, tblProducts.reorderpolicy, tblProducts.machinedaway, tblProducts.useotherm3XC, tblProducts.useotherm3MS, tblProducts.ShrinkWrap, tblProducts.ShrinkWrapPackSize, tblProducts.SW, tblProducts.samtype1, tblProducts.vtype1, tblProducts.vtype2, tblProducts.profile, tblProducts.productchamp, tblProducts.UOM, tblProducts.SAMPartGrp, tblProducts.PostingClass, tblProducts.ProductID
FROM tblProducts
```

This works fine and uploads all records in the table with new keys if i want to (I dont). I want to only recreate one product ive tried added the below

```
WHERE (((tblProducts.ProductID)=[tests]));
```

Where tests is a popupbox for User entry

i get an error below[image]

My primary key in the table is called [ProductID]. It is possible to add a WHERE [ProductID] = 1234 in this query somehow?

Comment: What is tests? You have provided virtually no information for anybody to be able to help. As much as I want to help you I simply do not have enough information.

Comment: Sorry tests is a popupbox where the user will input the variable. I dont want to insert ProductID as its an autonumber i want to only insert the one row the user specifies using a popupbox which = ProductID. if that makes sense.

Comment: Well then of course you are getting a primary key violation. You are inserting the exact same row back into the table. You might also want to look at parameterizing your queries, your example is wide open to sql injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the very last item in the column list of the INSERT INTO clause is `ProductID`. So, you are trying to insert a new row with an existing Primary Key value, and that won't work. As a simplified example,

```sql
INSERT INTO tblProducts (ProductDescription, ProductID)
SELECT tblProducts.ProductDescription, tblProducts.ProductID
FROM tblProducts
WHERE tblProducts.ProductID=1
```

will fail with a primary key violation. You need to remove ProductID from both the INSERT INTO and SELECT clauses, and only use it in the WHERE clause:

```sql
INSERT INTO tblProducts (ProductDescription)
SELECT tblProducts.ProductDescription
FROM tblProducts
WHERE tblProducts.ProductID=1
```

Comment: ahh when adding in the filter by productId access added in the fields again.. I'm an idiot. Thank you so much!